# Convert large KML coordinate datasets to UTM

Tags: data, units, conversion, geodesy

I was wondering if there are ways to convert massive amounts of KML coordinates into UTM coordinates using *Mathematica*.  Other programs would also be acceptable. Thanks.

I have the KML file from Google Earth and i need to convert thouse points to UTM, so I can represent the path in 3D by points.

Comment: What are KML and UTM?

Comment: I assume [Keyhole Markup Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) and [Universal Transverse Mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system).

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Have a look at the [KML Import page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/KML.html) and the [GeoProjectionData page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoProjectionData.html) and friends.